# How to catch the error thrown by an invalid URL using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, xmlhttprequest

I have not worked much with the `XMLHttpRequest` object in `JavaScript`. I am new to it. I have done many `jQuery` `Ajax` calls, but have not worked in much detail with the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

I am working through a book where they give some sample code using this object.

Here is some code the book uses when trying to deal with errors. It is supposed to catch the error thrown by the incorrect URL. But I can't get it to go it the `catch clause`:

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
try
{
     httpRequest.open("GET", "http://");
     httpRequest.send();
}
catch (error)
{
     alert("in catch clause");
}
```

I have even tried an invalid URL and still doesn't want to go into the `catch clause`:

```
httpRequest.open("GET", "gttp://");
```

Is it because the URL is a valid URL that it is not throwing an exception?

Comment: the error catched if you pass undefined variable `httpRequest.open("GET", not_defined);`

Comment: i've tried to `httpRequest.open("GET", false);` it calls http://OS/false and the same with null and undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
try
{
     httpRequest.open("GET", "http://",false);
     httpRequest.send();
}
catch (error)
{  
 
     alert("in catch clause");
}
```

The default `open` method is asynchronous and cannot be caught in try/catch block. This is because the entire code will get executed even before the open method is completed. `open` method has got another optional parameter called `async` which is boolean and default is `true`. Setting it to `false` will get the job done. If this value is false, the `send()` method does not return until the response is received.