# How can I handle the 404 error thrown by making an XMLHttpRequest to an invalid URL?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing code where I use a typical XMLHttpRequest to make API calls using user input. Sometimes, the user input is such that the API call made is to an invalid URL (to be more specific, the API is a thesaurus and when you use it to ask for a word not in the thesaurus, you just get a 404 error and the page doesn't exist). This is giving a 404 error (and then a CORS error that I think is just a side-effect of the original), and citing the request.send() line. My problem is that whatever I try, I cannot seem to find a way to handle the 404 error.

I' ve tried to catch the error and handle it in various parts of the code, but in each one the error is thrown and not handled. Places I've tried to handle the error:

- an "error" event listener. The callback is called, but the error has seemingly already been thrown and not handled
- In the "load" event listener
- the onreadystatechange function
- Putting the request.send() call in a try/catch block and making the call synchronous; like with the error event listener, the catch code is run but the error is still not handled and makes its way to the console. Note that this is the answer suggested by [How to catch the error thrown by an invalid URL using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337189/how-to-catch-the-error-thrown-by-an-invalid-url-using-xmlhttprequest) with a similar title, hence why I've made a new thread.

How can I properly handle this error so it won't be sent to console?

My code looks like (without most of the bulleted past attempts above):

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET",url, false);
req.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
... (handle response)
}
req.send(); //this is where the error comes in
```

Comment: `How can I properly handle this error so it won't be sent to console?` - sorry, but you can't stop that,

Comment: Sorry, can you explain why not? Usually isn't there some way to handle an error so that it is caught and then it won't go to console?

Comment: the console shows network responses, and there's nothing you can do to hide that from an end user

Comment: I had assumed that this error indicated a flaw in my program; so is this then not something I need to worry about fixing?

Comment: you are right, it is a flaw in your program - you're trying to access a resource that does not exist. But that's not a logic error, that's just an error as far as what you've tried to retrieve from the server. However, a 404 status is not an error as far as XMLHttpRequest goes, it's just a status code that, by convention, represents a condition where the requested resource is not found. But there's actually no http response status that will trigger an exception in javascript XHR/fetch/etc

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. I think I see what you mean now.

Comment: "a CORS error that I think is just a side-effect of the original" - since your code will still try to access the data from the request, even if it status is 404, the CORS error is not a side effect of 404 status, it's a side effect of trying to access a cross origin resource where the server does not let you access the resource. Of course, the server in question MAY issue CORS headers when accessing a valid resource, but there's no way to know from the code you posted

Comment: I'm using this API: https://words.bighugelabs.com/ ; I'm pretty sure it does issue CORS headers when accessing a valid resource because my request code works when the thesaurus has an entry for the word requested. And what I meant in saying that the CORS error is a side effect of the 404 status is that the server cannot issue CORS headers because it is not serving the requested page at all, does that make sense or am I wrong?

Comment: Also, if I'm correct in my last comments assertion, what's the neatest way to handle the CORS error? Making request.open synchronous and using a try/catch block around request.send() works but I'd rather not make the request synchronous. Is there a better way to handle it, perhaps in the load event handler?

Comment: easiest way to handle a CORS error is to NOT make requests for resources you are not "allowed" (by the server) to make

Comment: How can I do that in this case though, since I have to make the request in order to check if the API serves that page (and sometimes the API will serve the page without any errors successfully)?

Comment: CORS will trigger an error ... `req.addEventListener("error"`

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for spending so much time to help me, you've really helped me learn and saved me much time!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question with content from Jaromanda X's comments. 
"The console shows network responses, and there's nothing you can do to hide that from an end user," so as long as I'm making a request that leads to a 404 error, I cannot get it out of the console. Given that in my example I don't see a way around sometimes making 404 requests (because the request needs to be made to check if the thesaurus has a word in it, and if it does not a 404 will occur), there is no fix for this problem (and there is no need to fix it).

Comment: `so as long as I'm making a request that leads to a 404 error, I cannot get it out of the console` you can't hide ANY requests, regardless of status, from the console